# What does the f mean in f=d&amp?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe

I am currently trying to explain and annotate a piece of code for google maps in an iframe for some homework at school and I just wanted to know what certain things meant.

```
<input name="f" type="hidden" value="d">
src="https://www.google.com/maps?z=11&amp;f=d&amp;output=embed&amp;ll=40.7902,-73.9597">
```

I just wanted to know what the f and d meant in the formatting of the map, I've researched on here and google but found nothing, I know the z means the amount the map is zoomed in by but had no idea when it came to the f and d?

Comment: &amp; is the html encoded form of &. it's just f=d

Comment: `f` is the parameter name, `d` is its value.

Answer (score 0):

It is the old google format. &f=d will show the side destination panel.

Comment: So if I set the type of it to something different than hidden, it will appear?

Comment: @henry, no, `hidden` here refers to the visibility of the `<input>` element, not a map feature. It directs the browser not to display that input as an editable field on the screen.

Comment: Assuming that sending `d` as the value of the `f` parameter tells the webpage to display the side destination panel (I'll take your word for it @lostbard) then setting the value of the `f` parameter to something else should cause the visibility of that panel to change.